# Variables with static/const, which to use in this case?

Tags: c++, class, opengl, static, constants

I am trying to create a small "world" made out of blocks, similar to Voxel engines, but a little different.

For this, I thought about creating a class, say `Block`, that has a method `draw()`. Let's think of a `Block` as a cuboid. Then I can characterize every `Block` by its length, width, height, and draw it by scaling it via the model matrix for a fixed array of vertices (namely that of a unit cube centered around the origin).

My question is: what would be the best way to declare this array consisting of 8 vertices of type `GLfloat` (that is, 24 `GLfloat` entries). Since I may be having many blocks, I want the array to be saved somewhere only once, and every instance of `Block` shall use this exact array, instead of carrying it around with every `Block`. What's the best way to accomplish this?
Since I am quite new to this, I couldn't really understand if `static` or `const` (or both?) can be helpful here. I thought about doing

```
const GLfloat unit_cube_vertices = { ... };

class Block
{ ... };
```

Is there a better/canonical way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the array is to be used only by your class (or in relationship with the class), I'd declare it as part of the class (note that static here will mean there's only one copy), i.e.

```
class Block {
public:  // or private if not used anywhere else
    static const GLfloat unit_cube_vertices[24];
};
```

If it's to be used globally, keep it as you declared it.

Comment: Thanks! By "keep it as you declared it", do you mean I should not add a `static`, or does that not matter?

Comment: Depends on what you want to do with the array... if you are declaring it and only need it in the one source file, using `static` is appropriate (and it will mean you cannot use it in other source files).  If you want to use it in our source files, you'd generally put it as `extern` in a header file and then not use `static` in the source file.

Answer (score 1):

This question doesn't seem to have much to do with static/const. Those two keywords just tell C++ how the storage may be accessed, and where it should be visible. What you are doing is totally fine.

`const` means the variable mustn't be changed anymore. In rare cases, the compiler can optimize your code if it knows the values aren't going to change.

`static` refers to the visibility of the object in different compilation units (~different files in your project). Variables with `static` linkage will not be seen in other compilation units.